# How do I change background images like on the Flickr homepage?

Tags: javascript, animation, frontend

I'm trying to clone the Flickr homepage and I want the first image to drop in in .3s and then for the images to change every 4 seconds taking 1 second to transition unless ArrowLeft or ArrowRight is pressed, in the case of ArrowLeft the image should have a drop in animation to the previous image in the cycle and in the case of ArrowRight being pressed the image should drop in to the next image in the cycle and in the case of both the images should stay for 4 seconds NOT TRANSITIONING IN LESS TIME IF THE INTERVAL THAT STARTS ON PAGE LOAD IS INTERRUPTED. You can see what I mean on the [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/) homepage.

the following is a distillation of the problem in code.

html document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <script src="test.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background"></div>
    <div id='grid'>
        <header>header</header>
        <main>main</main>
        <footer>footer</footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css document

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  display: grid;
}

#background {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(./test_images/meditation.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-name: slideIn;
  transition: background-image 1s;
  z-index: 0;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 65px 1fr minmax(65px, auto);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: white;
}

main {
  color: white;
}

footer {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

#grid, #background {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
}
```

javascript document

```
let i = 0;
const backgroundImages = ['meditation.jpg', 'fish.jpg', 'fern.jpg', 'stars.jpg', 'northernLights.jpg', 'forest.jpg', 'mountains.jpg', 'horse.jpg', 'lion.jpg', 'engineer.jpg', 'computers.jpg'];

function changeImages () {
    i++;
    if (i == backgroundImages.length) {i = 0}
    document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundImage = 'url(./test_images/' + backgroundImages[i] + ')';
}

window.onload = function () {
    window.setInterval(changeImages, 4000);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        i--;
    } else if (event.key == "ArrowRight") {
        i++;
    }
    if (i == -1) {
        i = backgroundImages.length - 1;
    } else if (i >= backgroundImages.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById('background').style.backgroundImage = 'url(./test_images/' + backgroundImages[i] + ')';

    document.getElementById('background').animate([
        {transform: "translateY(-100%)"},
        {transform: 'translateY(0%)'}
    ], {
        duration: 300,
        iterations: 1
    })
    window.setInterval(changeImages, 4000);
}, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you set a new interval, cancel the old interval using [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval):

```
let intervalId;
window.onload = function () {
    intervalId = window.setInterval(changeImages, 4000);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    .....
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = window.setInterval(changeImages, 4000);
}, false)
```